# Python Tkinter get image of whats behind a window

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, tkinter

Well i am creating a utility for my own needs, that being to help improve my reading on the computer. What i need to do is create a tool which can add a colour filter to a section of the screen, as well as add zoom. The first thing was easy to do, i set the attributes to add alpha, topmost and gave a frame a set bg colour.

What i dont know how to do is the zoom. I was thinking of getting a screen capture cut the selected bit apply image transformation then render it in the window. Of course the utility window will also be drawn and obscure the screen capture. I dont know tkinter well enough and i really want to avoid doing GDI work, but if someone has a solution with it i dont mind using it. Clearly referencing GDI, im making it to run on windows.

Optional: Something i have a work around for but would be nice to have is the ability to click through a window, but i doubt i can do that with tkinter.

EDIT: Since im getting negative votes, and i don't know why please help me improve with a comment.

I'm not looking for someone to do the work for me i just want a hint on what might be the right way to do this. With the main problem being how to get a image for whats underneath the Tkinter window so i can process it.

Comment: You're question lacks a very important piece of information, and that's the OS you're developing on. Anyway, I upvoted you since it's not a bad question though the problem could be clearer. Make the question title more specific, e.g. "How to capture image of what's behind a Tk window?"

Comment: Thank you, i have added windows tag and new name. It was already mention maybe not clear enough that i was running it on windows. I hope the tag makes it clearer.