# How to capture image behind window in python (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, blur

I like to capture pixels behind the window, blur them with the `Pillow` package and finally display them as image on a frame.
I can't find anything but an unanswered question: [Python Tkinter get image of whats behind a window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095317/python-tkinter-get-image-of-whats-behind-a-window)

Is it possible to do it in Python 3.7?

Here is an example how the code will be:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.overrideredirect(True)
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self, relief="flat", bd=0)

        self.label = tk.Label()

    def mainloop(self, n=0):
        while self.winfo_exists():
            background = Image.frombytes("RGB", ..., ...)
            tk_backkground = ImageTk.PhotoImage(background)

            self.label.config(image=tk_backkground)
            self.update()
            self.update_idletasks()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = MainWindow()
    root.mainloop()
```

if you need more information, just say it.

*(Sorry for my bad English)*

Comment: ***"Is it possible to do "***: Yes if you `.withdraw()` your `MainWindow` before `grab` the pixel or **before** the `MainWindow` is shown.

Comment: @stovfl That will flicker the window, and I want it so it's completely smooth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in windows you can use BlurWindow

> python -m pip install BlurWindow

```
from tkinter import *
from ctypes import windll

from BlurWindow.blurWindow import blur

root = Tk()
root.config(bg='green')

root.wm_attributes("-transparent", 'green')
root.geometry('500x400')

root.update()

hWnd = windll.user32.GetForegroundWindow()
blur(hWnd)



def color(hex):
    hWnd = windll.user32.GetForegroundWindow()
    blur(hWnd,hexColor=hex)
    

e = Entry(width=9)
e.insert(0,'#12121240')

e.pack()
b = Button(text='Apply',command=lambda:[color(e.get())])
b.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

[image: win11]